# Pandas: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, pandas

input is,

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'NaN','abj','1/1/2021'],
               [2,'[{"Result":"00018"},{"Result":"00065"}]','abj','1/1/2021'],
               [3,'','abj','1/1/2021']],
                 columns = ['ID','SKU','NOTES','Date'])
```

expected result

```
        ID     SKU   NOTES
     0  1             abj
     1  2    00018    abj
     2  2    00065    abj
     3  3             abj
```

tried the below, but gives an error

```
df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(lambda x : [ i['Result']  for i in  json.loads(x)])

df.explode('SKU')
```

Results error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Clearly anfd `x` isn’t a JSON string. Have you tried printing it? Or expand your comprehension into a for loop so you can print each value. Or use a named function instead of a lambda, so you can debug it

Comment: the same code works when there are no 'NaN or ''

Comment: Yes a NaN wouldn’t decode as JSON. So remove them, replace with ‘[]’? Sounds like you know what the problem is.

Comment: in `lambda` you should use some if/else and skip `json` when you have `NaN` or `""`

Answer (score 0):

You should check what you have in `x` and skip `json`

Longer version but more readable

```
def convert(text):
    if text not in ('', 'NaN'):
        data = [i['Result'] for i in json.loads(text)]
    else:
        data = ''
    return data

df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(convert)
```

Shorter version:

```
df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(lambda x : [i['Result'] for i in json.loads(x)] if x not in ('', 'NaN') else "")
```

---

**EDIT:**

More universal version - it uses `try/except` so it should work with other wrong strings

```
def convert(text):
    try:   
        data = [i['Result'] for i in json.loads(text)]
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'exeption: "{text}" : {ex}')
        data = ''
    return data

df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(convert)
```

---

Full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1,'NaN','abj','1/1/2021'],
        [2,'[{"Result":"00018"},{"Result":"00065"}]','abj','1/1/2021'],
        [3,'','abj','1/1/2021']
     ], columns=['ID','SKU','NOTES','Date'])

print(df)

def convert(text):
    try:   
        data = [i['Result'] for i in json.loads(text)]
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'exeption: "{text}" : {ex}')
        data = ''
    return data

df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(convert)
#df.SKU = df.SKU.apply(lambda x : [i['Result'] for i in json.loads(x)] if x not in ('', 'NaN') else "")

df = df.explode('SKU')

print(df)
```